# How to get values of checkbox in node js using ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, checkbox, ejs, formidable

**My Code:**

**Html File:**

```
<form action="/form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
       Email: <input type="email" name="email" /> <br>
       Age: <input type="number" name="age" /> <br>
       Address: <textarea name="address" rows="10" cols="15"> </textarea><br>
       Category: <select name="cat">
                   <option value="1">Php</option>
                   <option value="2">NodeJs</option>
                   <option value="3">jQuery</option>
                 </select><br>
       Gender: <input type="radio" name="gen" value="m"/> Male
               <input type="radio" name="gen" value="f"/> Female
       Hobby:   <input type="checkbox" name="hob[]" value="cri"/> cricket
                <input type="checkbox" name="hob[]" value="fot"/> football
                <input type="checkbox" name="hob[]" value="swi"/> swimming
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Output Console in NodeJs:**

```
{ name: 'My name',
  email: 'myname@xyz.co',
  age: '23',
  address: 'xyz loaacation pqr city ',
  cat: '1',
  gen: 'm',
  'hob[]': 'cri' }
```

I am using formidable for file upload and it provides with fields and files options.
Now all the above fields give me proper output when supplied data except for checkbox which i have no idea how or what to do to get output.

to get the above output i have just typed-> `console.log(fields)`;
and you can access a property by ex:- `fields.field_name`.  but it doesn't work for checkboxes.

what i want is to get the checkbox value to display to the user. checkbox can have multiple values selected.

Thank you.

Comment: ur code "hobby" must be like 
name="hob[cri]" value="cricket"
name="hob[fot]" value="football"
try this ( haven't tested for ur requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You can access that with bracket notation `fields['hob[]']`.

Comment: Nope that didnt work, it only showed the last value which was selected. so if i select cricket and football it shows fot.   Thanks for the attempt

Comment: Well, I receive array of checked values when selecting multiple. But I'm not using multipart. Maybe that's the difference. In the worst case you could always use different names for each checkbox.

Comment: i like the idea of using diffrent names for each checkbox. But then it would be a mess if i needed to generate checkbox based on database values. but still i would like to use the idea of diffrent names. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample form:
<!-- RADIO BUTTONS -->
   <p>
      <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="M" checked>
      <label for="male">Male</label>
   </p>
   <p>
       <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="F">
      <label for="female">Female</label>
   </p>

    <button type="submit" class="btn ">Sign up</button>
```

To extract our value from the checkbox we can do so by *req.body.gender* and value of M/F will be stored in the person object

```
 let person = {
  gender: req.body.gender 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `.ejs` file we will following.

```
<form action="/addhobby" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Hobbies</h5>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="stuhobbies" value="sing"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Sing</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="stuhobbies" value="guitarplay"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>GuitarPlay</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="stuhobbies" value="cricket"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Cricket</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="stuhobbies" value="football"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Football</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
    Add
</button>
```

now in the action or in the route handling file we do following.

```
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/addhobby', ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) => {    
    const { stuhobbies } = req.body;
    console.log(stuhobbies);
});
```